# Any way to know what wakes an Mac up?

Tags: mac, sleep-wake

Regularly while sleeping my Mac wakes up and i'd like to know if there is some kind of log of what trigged the waking. (Mouse click ? Keyboard ? WOL Magic Packet ? Something else ?)

I'm on late 2012 iMac with 10.8.3

PS: "Wake for network access" is enabled.

Comment: How about the bluetooth mouse and keyboard. My guess is there's a setting that allows them to wake the computer and that setting is adjustable.

Comment: I only use the Bluetooth Keyboard, the mouse is Wired. FYI it's on the mouse's LED that I see that the Mac is on. (Screen stays off). But I'l try disabling the option you mentioned.

Comment: Do you have a wireless or wired LAN?

Comment: I use only my Ethernet connection.

Comment: Then disable "Wake for network access". See if you still have the issue. I can not use this option because probably my WRT54GL wakes my iMac from sleep.

Comment: Well it seems that it was my problem. My Mac gets woken up by a network access...

Comment: If you want WOL, you can go wireless with airport express (I think it supports wake up over wireless). If wake up is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer to myself

```
syslog |grep -i "Wake reason"
```

gives the wake reason from the syslog for example : RTC, GiGE, Bonjour etc.

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences under Energy Saver, is there a check in the checkbox for *Enable Power Nap while plugged into a power adapter*?

If so, then this is possibly why your iMac is waking up.  The description of Power Nap in System Preferences says: "While sleeping, your Mac can back up using Time Machine and periodically check for new email, calendar, and other iCloud updates".

Comment: It's not a MacBook therefore I haven't PowerNap

Comment: Yikes!  You are correct, Power Nap is a laptop-only feature - my apologies!  Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5394